# merging /var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb possible?

Tags: smart

I had to by an new Harddrive.

```
smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST1000LX015-1U7172
Serial Number:    WES3C2P0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0a87cea5e
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jun 10 10:11:39 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

I tried to update the database.

```
 update-smart-drivedb 
/var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb.h.error: rejected by /usr/sbin/smartctl, probably no longer compatible
```

I changed the Download-src to

```
# Download URL for sourceforge code browser
SRCEXPR='http://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/code/HEAD/tree/$location/smartmontools/drivedb.h?format=raw'
```

in /usr/sbin/update-smart-drivedb

Same result.  I try to install smartmontools from unstable, but then my System is more from unstable than from jessie. So I thought I can download the Package with wget an merge the files. Because I have some older HD IDE and I'm not sure if they are in the newer drivedb from unstable.

```
file /var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb
/var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Is this possible and then yes, how?

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question about merging, so I’m leaving it as a comment: you can install an up-to-date `smartmontools` from Jessie backports. In any case, not having the device in the `smartctl` database isn’t really a problem.

Comment: @StephenKitt It _is_ a problem if you actually want to monitor particular parameters and your model is not recognized.

Comment: Oh, i was not sure. Fut I had a temperatur problem, so I need to monitor it whole

Comment: @Sato I stand (or rather sit) corrected, thanks. (I should have written two comments, I would have been able to delete the misleading info...)

Comment: The latest `smartctl` doesn’t appear to contain anything matching this particular drive.

Comment: I thought it is https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/825

Comment: Ah yes, it is, but that hasn’t been added to the database yet (even in upstream source control).